# Get-ItemProperty output between "" quotes

Tags: powershell, format, output, quotes

Is there any way to get the "Get-ItemPropertyValue" output separated by semicolon each element and the whole output between quoutes?

For example:

`Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanManServer\Parameters' -Name NullSessionPipes`

Now the output is:

> netlogon samr lsarpc

The desired output is:

> "netlogon,samr,lsarpc"

I tried the backtick escape character, but unfortunately no luck.

Many thanks for help!

Comment: `'"{0}"' -f ((Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanManServer\Parameters' -Name NullSessionPipes) -join ',')`

Comment: Thanks, it looks good for me. Now the output is ",netlogon,samr,lsarpc". Is there a way to remove the first comma?

Comment: That would indicate the first value coming from `Get-ItemPropertyValue` is an empty string. You can filter it out with `(Get-ItemPropertyValue ... |Where-Object {$_})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by using the `-join` operator on the desired string values to create a string like `netlogon,samr,lsarpc`:

```
$values = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanManServer\Parameters' -Name NullSessionPipes |Where-Object { $_ <# this will remove empty values #> }
$string = $values -join ','
```

Now we just need to embed it in a string surrounded by literal `"`'s, my preference would be to use the `-f` operator:

```
'"{0}"' -f $string
```